# How to filter a Pandas dataframe with varying number of keyword conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I understand the concept of using & to filter DataFrame rows based on more than one condition, but how can I write this in an iterative way that depends on the number of conditions (**kwargs) I pass into a function?

I am trying to do so within a for loop that iterates through a list of DataFrames (replist). The keywords passed are strings, and keys for those strings correspond with another dictionary (kwarg_dict). Essentially, if I pass

```
func(fruit='apple', veggie='kale')
```

I want to build a DataFrame from the dataframes contained in replist for which the fruit column is 'apple' and the veggie column is 'kale. But, if I then pass

```
func(fruit='apple', veggie='kale', dessert='cake')
```

I want to build a DataFrame with all three arguments considered. The user should be able to pass any number of arguments, so the number of logical &s will differ.

For instance, if I had two keywords, I would use:

```
sub_df = pd.concat(
         [sub_df, replist[i][
                             (replist[i][kwarg_dict[list(kwargs)[0]]] == kwargs[list(kwargs)[0]]) &
                             (replist[i][kwarg_dict[list(kwargs)[1]]] == kwargs[list(kwargs)[1]])
                              ]
          ])
```

But for three keywords, I would use:

```
sub_df = pd.concat(
         [sub_df, replist[i][
                             (replist[i][kwarg_dict[list(kwargs)[0]]] == kwargs[list(kwargs)[0]]) &
                             (replist[i][kwarg_dict[list(kwargs)[1]]] == kwargs[list(kwargs)[1]]) &
                             (replist[i][kwarg_dict[list(kwargs)[2]]] == kwargs[list(kwargs)[2]])
                              ]
          ])
```

This does what I want, but obviously isn't general for any number of keywords passed.

It's evident to me I need to iterate over range(len(kwargs)) but I'm not sure how to string output of that iteration together with logical & statements the way I've shown above. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension to generalize your example:

```py
f = [replist[i][kwarg_dict[var]] == kwargs[var] for var in list(kwargs)]
pd.concat([subdf, replist[i][f]])
```

However, I do think you are better off using [`df.Filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and simply passing `kwargs.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way (not very elegant but it does the trick) :

```
test = eval(" & ".join(["(replist[{0}]['{1}'] == '{2}')".format(i, k, v) for k, v in kwarg_dict.items()]))

sub_df = pd.concat([sub_df, replist[i][test]])
```